# Converting coordinates to points in order to use the Near Analysis Model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

What I need to the publish an Near Analysis model which accept X,Y or Lon,Lat as input.

Unfortunately,  **the input of Near Analysis should be features like point or line(Not a pair of number). The following shows the definition of Near Analysis.**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour]. Converting coordinates to points would be the obvious solution. Please [edit] the question to specify what you  have tried and ask an explicit question.

Comment: @Vince is there any model that can convert coordinates to  points?

Comment: Please **edit the question** to ask your question. Comments are reserved for requests for clarification.

Comment: @Vince I just edited the question. Could you pls teach me how to convert a x,y or lat, lon pair to a point feature in order to use near analysis?

Answer (score 1):

For ArcGIS this link should help you: [How To: Import XY data tables to ArcMap and convert the data to a shapefile](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012745)